# Is there a convenience method to delete a pin in the Pinterest IOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, pinterest

Per the documentation (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/ios/) there's a method to delete a board `PDKClient.sharedInstance().deleteBoard`but I don't see anything to delete a pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this... a pull request was added re: this issue:  https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/pull/56